# How to set row selection to newly added row?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I need to set selection to a newly added row.
When `$scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow(newObject)` is entered, the grid's row model does not have the new row and thus can not select it.
After method `addRow` is finished, the grid shows the new row (and the data) but no selection was made.

My test code:

```
$scope.addRow = function() {
    $scope.gridOptions.data.unshift({
        // my new data object
    });

    var newObject = $scope.gridOptions.data[0];
    $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow(newObject);
};
```

How can I achieve this behavior?

Is there an event like 'rowAdded' in angularjs ui-grid I have to listen to?
Is there anywhere a comprehensive list of events fired by ui-grid?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can event listeners on row, column and so on. The documentation is here http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:Grid

You can add the data listener in onRegisterApi like below,

```
onRegisterApi : function(gridApi)
            {
                if(!$scope.gridApi) 
                {
                    $scope.gridApi = gridApi; 
                    $scope.gridApi.grid.registerDataChangeCallback(function(data)
                    {
                      $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0]);
                    }, [uiGridConstants.dataChange.ROW]);
                }
            }
```

and select any row you want to select.

Here is a working plnkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/NjnMb65w86L0bKmkkJp0?p=preview