# Programatically select row in UI-Grid without listener

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

I want to select all rows of a grid by default, and I managed to do so by adding a data listener in onRegisterApi as specified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329748/how-to-set-row-selection-to-newly-added-row?answertab=active#tab-top):

```
onRegisterApi : function(gridApi)
    {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi; 
      $scope.gridApi.grid.registerDataChangeCallback(function(data)
        {
          $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0]);
        }, [uiGridConstants.dataChange.ROW]);
    }
```

Working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/dzf6PZwKdZmSNvKzQeYH?p=preview

However, I don't understand why it doesn't work without a listener, like

```
onRegisterApi : function(gridApi)
    {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi; 
        _.each($scope.gridOptions.data, function(companies, index){
          $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[index]);
      });

    }
```

Non-working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/XOliwXn2MLyH6nqO7pp4?p=preview

Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used below code for angular 1.5.0 version. It is working for me.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', 'uiGridConstants','$location', function ($scope, $http, $interval, uiGridConstants, $location) { ...............
```

// $interval whilst we wait for the grid to digest the data we just gave it

```
$interval( function() {$scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0]);}, 0, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering such an old question!

Comment: Wow, this really works. I tried without the interval and no rows were selected. With interval it worked perfect. Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

It does work, you just need to wait for the grid to be loaded, for example with a small timeout. This way the browser renders your DOM and executes the JS afterwards, even with very small timeout. [See this answer about timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/779785/4299313).

I [updated your Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ovcHehPrIyAtjtenevRN?p=preview).

```
setTimeout(function(){
  _.each($scope.gridOptions.data, function(companies, index){
    $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[index]);
  });
}, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but according to https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/2267#issuecomment-128551701 there should be no more $timeout needed.